# Always ON - What is the difference between the virtual cluster name and Listener

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering, failover

In clustering you specify DNS name/IP address of cluster that is then used by all applications. In case of failover, the same DNS name/IP address will point to the appropriate database server.

In Always on Availability Groups, there is concept of Listener which to my understanding does the same as above, so do we really need a Listener when the Failover clustering already handles this concept (IP address) of failover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> do we really need a Listener when the Failover clustering already handles this concept (IP address) of failover?

A SQL Server Failover Cluster Instance (FCI) will always have a "Network name resource" for clients to connect to the active node.

But with AlwaysOn Availability Groups it is optional, and created through SQL Server.  If you don't create an AG Listener, the Windows cluster will not have any IP address or hostname that moves along with the AG.

In any case an AG Listener is a Windows Server Failover Clustering "Network name resource", and so is confined to a single Cluster.  If you have a [Distributed Availability Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/distributed-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017) which spans multiple Clusters, or a [Read-Scale Availability Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/read-scale-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017) which has no cluster, then you can't have an AG Listener.  (Although with a Distributed AG each participating AG can have its own listener).

Comment: Is Listener a concept of Clustering or Availability Groups?

Comment: See update to answer.

Comment: I have created a read scale AG, and the UI allows me to configure the listener. Should I give it a name and IP of the primary or do I skip this step?

Comment: Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-read-scale-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver16#connect-to-read-only-secondary-replicas  You can give the listener its own name and the IP of the primary, and then recreate it with the same name and different IP on the secondary in a DR or other manual failover.  So your clients are bound to the listener name, not directly to the name of the primary.

Comment: After creating the listener do I need to ask my network admin to add the listener name and IP as a DNS entry?

Comment: If you have a cluster, I know it will try to register the listener in DNS.  Not sure in the case you don't have a cluster.  In any case if the server doesn't have permissions to add the DNS entry your network admin will need to do it.  Same with SPNs.